# Graphic card not screwed to chassis

Tags: graphics-card, computer-building, case

I recently brought an AMD Radeon HD 6450 1gb (sapphire) graphic card but while installing this graphic card to pci x16 expansion slot(motherboard D102GGC2), the cabinet/chassis was causing problems.

So, I removed the metal inserts from the cabinet. The Red circle area shown in image was all removed by me, so that the graphic card could fit easily.

But, Now I am worried because the Graphic card is just supported by the PCI x16 slot and I heard that expansion card should be grounded.

**So,I just want to know will this cause any problem to my graphic card in any way?**

[image]

Comment: You had to remove three of the brackets to make the card fit?  How does it mount?

Comment: I removed the near by all metal brackets to fit my graphic card. Now, it is only supported by graphic card slot.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you didn't fix the cards bracket to the chassis with the screw(s) provided? You say you're worried that the card is only supported by the PCIe slot (which is indeed a problem waiting to happen), so why do you even have to ask about this? I mean, both the graphics card's and motherboard's manuals probably tell you to fix expansion cards to the chassis.

Comment: I would not trust the PCIe slot retention mechanism to hold the graphics card in place long term. I'd worry about it wiggling out.

Comment: @Indrek : Read my post carefully. I removed the cards bracket because it was not allowing my graphic card to attach it to my graphic card slot. So, I removed it to install graphic card.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz : Can you tell any idea by which I can make my graphic card firm, so that it won't come out.

Comment: @FrozenKing: Figure out why it isn't fitting and make it fit. Most of the time, this is possible.

Comment: @FrozenKing I thought that by "metal inserts from the cabinet" you meant removing a few extra dummy slot covers, in order to fit your card. If that's not the case, then what exactly *did* you remove? The mounting bracket from the card itself? The whole card support structure of the chassis? The picture is pretty vague.

Comment: @Indrek : Yes in order to fit graphic card I removed dummy slot covers as well as the upper metal part where we screw the card. I just wanted to know that is it safe, if only it is connected to PCIE slot and was there any necessity that card should be in contact with the cabinet.

Comment: @FrozenKing Put that metal part of the chassis (not the dummy covers) back and figure out why your card doesn't fit. Because it should. All expansion cards should be fixed to the chassis for mechanical support, especially larger and heavier ones like graphics cards.

Comment: I would love to see a picture of this setup - there is no reason the card should not fit in a chassis like that unless it's damaged. Indrek and David Schwartz are absolutely right here.

Comment: So you're saying that the graphics card does not come with a metal bracket?  Or did you remove the bracket from the card for some reason?

Comment: I haven't removed the metal bracket from graphic card. I removed the metal brackets from the cabinet all of them as well as the top layer of metal where we put screw to hold the card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connector provides [plenty of grounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#Pinout).  And the [PCIe specification](http://www.pcisig.com/members/downloads/specifications/pciexpress/PCI_Express_CEM_1.1_.pdf) requires keep-out zones be around the mounting holes (where the I/O bracket is mounted to the PCB) so as to prevent short-outs on the I/O bracket.  So there shouldn't be any electrical connections to the chassis at all.

Comment: Nice. From "I do not think so" (my answer) to clear hard reasoning. +1

Answer (score 2):

Grounded? Via the case? I doubt that.

I do not have any hard evidence except that both my GPUs at home do **not** make electric contact except via the PCIe slot and for the high end card for PCIe slot and the additional power connectors. Neither of them get anything but physical support from the chassis.

Having said that: Screwing it down so it does not fall or vibrate out of the PCIe connector is a good idea.

Comment: So you mean to say it is Ok , if graphic card is not in contact with any metal part of the chassis!!

Comment: To be honest, you might be right - I know the IO plate brackets on some motherboards have flanges for grounding purposes, so I've always assumed expansion cards had the same concerns, but that's just an assumption.  (Of course, I've run plenty of systems not in a chassis at all with GPUs with no problems so really it's not a big deal...I'd be more worried about screwing it down so it doesn't go anywhere!)

Comment: @shinrai: Good point about running open systems. I done that in the past, as have many others (including benchmark sites).

Comment: Hey Hennes and Shinrai can you just tell any ideas by which I can make my graphic card more stable??

Comment: @FrozenKing - Sure, you anchor it to something.  With a screw.  (Or I guess you could get by with ziptying it down or something.)

Comment: @Shinrai : It won't be possible with screw, since I removed the upper metal where we used to screw it :)

Comment: @FrozenKing - I am having trouble picturing why this thing would be that difficult to install...but obviously if you've removed the entire support structure things will be hard.

Comment: Ya now u got the problem I removed the support structure for the card from the cabinet since it was causing me problems in installing the card...and I thought the support structures in cabinet are made for grounding of card...thats y I asked this question.

Comment: @FrozenKing - "it was causing me problems in installing the card" is the part that confuses me.  These things are standardized, it should have caused you problems unless something was damaged...